# Are these two questions duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The questions:
[How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/1048572) (Oct. 2008, ~1300 upvotes)
and
[Determine whether an array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181575/1048572) (Jul. 2009, ~300 upvotes)
are very similar.

The first asks:

> What is the most concise and efficient way to find out if a JavaScript array contains an obj?

While the second says:

> i need to determine if a value exists in an array using javascript.

Both have the same kind of answers.

What should happen to them? Shall I close the second as a duplicate of the first? Should they be merged (as both contain high-quality answers)?

Comment: 1 is about finding an object in an array, the other is about finding a value in an array. Keep them as they are. I'd say, those are different subjects. However, I noticed the "Object" one only has "value" answers... In that clase, close the object one.

Comment: @Cerbrus: An object is just a value.

Comment: I would advise to leave both of them to let someone plainly writes an answer that highlight the difference between "==" and "===".